# How to build an ant target from DOS command-line when target starts with a '-' as in -ivy-info

Tags: ant, build-automation

While troubleshooting a problem with [apache-ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), I want to call an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) target named ***-ivy-info*** defined in my build.xml.  My -ivy-info target calls the [ivy:info](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/info.html) task and the [ivy:buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) task and calculates the next revision number.

Problem is the ant command-line interprets the -ivy-info as a command-line option then fails with: `Unknown argument: -ivy-info`

One workaround I have found is to change the default target to -ivy-info via the first line of build.xml: `<project name="my.project" default="-ivy-info">` and then run ant with no arguments, which works fine.

Other options are to rename the -ivy-info target so it does not start with a '-' character, or to create a new empty target with a name not starting with '-' and that includes -ivy-info as a dependency.

However I still want to know if there is any way that **doesn't involve first editing build files**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything starting with a "-" will be interpreted into an command-line argument, not a target. For example, there are usages like `ant -f build-actual.xml` or `ant -Dproperty=value` -- they are all Ant's command-line arguments. If you pass `-ivy-info` from command-line, of course, it is treated as an argument.

There's no way to run `-ivy-info` directly from command-line due to the argument parsing; and specifying it as the default target works because it is parsed by the xml parser, not command-line argument parser.

With this, when writing a build file, one can use "-" to **prevent** a target from being called directly from command-line (just like `private` methods in OO-languages). If the build file is not written by you, then the author doesn't want you to run it directly from command-line.

If you are sure that the target can be called directly from command-line, just rename it.